# DomainContext, Silverlight 3, code behind, Edit EntitySet

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, wcf-ria-services, entityset

I'm trying to get my brain wraped around Silverlight RIA

I'm to a point where I can create an object with a collection of objects which also has a collection of objects.

Test object that holds test questions, that holds question answers.

I have the associations set up and the the data makes it to to silverlight app.

So in my loaded callback....i can see all the data in up

```
   private void TestLoaded(LoadOperation lo)
    {
            var ce =dc.Tests.CanEdit;
            dc.Tests.ToList()[0].TestQuestions.ToList()[0].StudentAnswerID = 2;
    }
```

var ce =dc.Tests.CanEdit; //CanEdit = true

but the next line gives the error:
This EntitySet of type 'SilverlightApplication2.Web.Question' does not support the 'Edit' operation.

**So my question is why does CanEdit =  true?
And what is a more graceful way of setting the value in code behind?**

rest of the code.....

```
        public class Test
    {
        private List<Question> _testQuestions = new List<Question>();

        [Key]
        public int TestID { get; set; }

        public string TestName { get; set; }


        [Include]
        [Association("Assoc1", "TestID", "TestID,QuestionID")]
        public List<Question> TestQuestions
        {
            get { return _testQuestions; }
            set { _testQuestions = value; }
        }
    }


    public class Question
    {
        private List<Answer> _questionAnswers = new List<Answer>();

        [Key]
        public int TestID { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int QuestionID { get; set; }

        public string QuestionText { get; set; }

        public int CorrectAnswerID { get; set; }
        public int StudentAnswerID { get; set; }

        [Include]
        [Association("Assoc2", "QuestionID", "QuestionID,AnswerID")]
        public List<Answer> QuestionAnswers
        {
            get { return _questionAnswers; }
            set { _questionAnswers = value; }
        }
    }



    public class Answer
    {
        [Key]
        public int QuestionID { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int AnswerID { get; set; }

        public string AnswerText { get; set; }
    }
```

//data populator

```
 public class TestBuilder
{

    public List<Test> MakeATest()
    {
        var ret = new List<Test>();

        var t = new Test()
        {
            TestID = 1,
            TestName = "The Test",
        };

        var tq = new Question() { TestID = 1, QuestionID = 1, CorrectAnswerID=1,  QuestionText = "T1Q1" };

        var a = new Answer() { QuestionID = 1, AnswerID = 1, AnswerText = "T1Q1A1" };
        tq.QuestionAnswers.Add(a);

        a = new Answer() { QuestionID = 1, AnswerID = 2, AnswerText = "T1Q1A2" };
        tq.QuestionAnswers.Add(a);

        a = new Answer() { QuestionID = 1, AnswerID = 3, AnswerText = "T1Q1A3" };
        tq.QuestionAnswers.Add(a);

        a = new Answer() { QuestionID = 1, AnswerID = 4, AnswerText = "T1Q1A4" };
        tq.QuestionAnswers.Add(a);
        t.TestQuestions.Add(tq);


        //second question
        tq = new Question() { TestID = 1, QuestionID = 2, CorrectAnswerID = 3, QuestionText = "T1Q2" };

        a = new Answer() { QuestionID = 2, AnswerID = 1, AnswerText = "T1Q2A1" };
        tq.QuestionAnswers.Add(a);

        a = new Answer() { QuestionID = 2, AnswerID = 2, AnswerText = "T1Q2A2" };
        tq.QuestionAnswers.Add(a);

        a = new Answer() { QuestionID = 2, AnswerID = 3, AnswerText = "T1Q2A3" };
        tq.QuestionAnswers.Add(a);

        a = new Answer() { QuestionID = 2, AnswerID = 4, AnswerText = "T1Q2A4" };
        tq.QuestionAnswers.Add(a);
        t.TestQuestions.Add(tq);


        //third question
        tq = new Question() { TestID = 1, QuestionID =3, CorrectAnswerID = 4, QuestionText = "T1Q3" };

        a = new Answer() { QuestionID = 3, AnswerID = 1, AnswerText = "T1Q3A1" };
        tq.QuestionAnswers.Add(a);

        a = new Answer() { QuestionID = 3, AnswerID = 2, AnswerText = "T1Q3A2" };
        tq.QuestionAnswers.Add(a);

        a = new Answer() { QuestionID = 3, AnswerID = 3, AnswerText = "T1Q3A3" };
        tq.QuestionAnswers.Add(a);

        a = new Answer() { QuestionID = 3, AnswerID = 4, AnswerText = "T1Q3A4" };
        tq.QuestionAnswers.Add(a);
        t.TestQuestions.Add(tq);

        ret.Add(t);

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Domain Service.....

```
 [EnableClientAccess()]
public class TestDomainService : DomainService
{
    public IEnumerable<Test> GetTest()
    {
        var tb = new TestBuilder();
        return tb.MakeATest();
    }

    public void InsertTest(Test currentData)
    {}

    public void UpdateTest(Test currentData)
    {}

    public void DeleteTest(Test currentData)
    {}
}
```

Silverlight side......

```
      private void GetTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dc.Load(dc.GetTestQuery(),
                LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent ,
                TestLoaded,
                null);
    }


    private void TestLoaded(LoadOperation lo)
    {
            var ce =dc.Tests.CanEdit;
            dc.Tests.ToList()[0].TestQuestions.ToList()[0].StudentAnswerID = 2;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you calling ToList()? RIA returns an EntitySet which inherits from IEnumerable so you shouldnt need to put it in a list. I would suggest trying a linq statement like:

```
using System.Linq;
Test mytest = dc.Tests.Where( x=> x.StudentAnswerID = 2).FirstorDefault();
```

As to the editing problem... If you are using Entity Framework as your data model be sure to check the checkbox "enable editing" when you create your domain service. CanEdit is a readonly value that tells you whether or not editing is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, @johnnywhoop, you know you can give the FirstorDefault a predicate, right?  Meaning, instead of saying:

```
Test mytest = dc.Tests.Where( x=> x.StudentAnswerID = 2).FirstorDefault();
```

You should say:

```
Test mytest = dc.Tests.FirstorDefault(x=> x.StudentAnswerID == 2);
```

Also, you'll want to give the "==" operator and not the "=" operator.  Otherwise you're just setting it.  Well, actually, it wouldn't build.